# modx custom tables

Tags: database, database-design, modx, modx-revolution

I want to create an application which needs some database tables.
Basically, I want to extend the user with some new attributes (Facebook page, fax, contacts ...,).

I want to do it by having the userId as a foreign key and the rest of the attributes will be in a new table.
Do I extend the login package I am using already?

Do I create a new component with all the file structure it needs as here:http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Developing+an+Extra+in+MODX+Revolution?

The data will be inserted, edited at front-end by a user. Do I need to create a component? If not, should I?

Also, should I create the tables through phpMyAdmin directly?

Please help me out as I am really confused of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would probably be best following the "simple" examples given in this doc:
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Extending+modUser

You can create the table in phpMyAdmin, just take care to ensure the table structure matches your schema perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

All, what you need - http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Using+Custom+Database+Tables+in+your+3rd+Party+Components . In this case, you do not need to create a table through phpmyadmin

Comment: Do i create a new component with all the file structure it needs, for adding some new tables? I really dont need a component i think, though. I want to create some tables and interract with them at front-end. What i am afraid of creating the tables is a future modx update may affect my actions. I am sorry for being ignorant but is my start in modx.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a few fields to add the simple way to go is to use the modx user profile extended attributes - that way you don't have to write any code, all the attribs are controlled with the extras that come with the login package [profile etc]

Take a look at the profile docs: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Login.Register and the "useExtended" attribute.  Simply by setting that flag the extra fields in your register form will be stored as a json array in the user attributes table.

Comment: thanks but there are more than just a few fields. I 'am going to examine the other two options.